# requests mock library does not work within spark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, python-requests, mocking

In `foreachPartition()` of Spark, I call to an API and I want to mock this API,
so this is what I did:

```
with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
    m.get('http://blablabla1.com:90', status_code=202)
    print(requests.get('http://blablabla1.com:90').status_code)

    def f(x):
        print(requests.get('http://blablabla1.com:90').status_code)
    sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5], 2).foreachPartition(f)
```

The first time I print the status code I get 202 but for the second time I get connection refused.

The question is how can I mock requests so when it is being called within spark it will still use the mock? the actual implementation is that the foreachPartition gets a url and call it, so I can't insert mock inside this code, only in the outside

Thanks

Comment: This inner function, shouldn't return the status code instead print?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the call requests.get('...') fails. Anyway I did it with Flask using the IP of the driver